# What is the asymptotic growth rate of the product of divisor function up to n

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This was asked in mathstackexchange (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472932/is-the-asymptotic-growth-rate-of-the-product-of-divisor-function-up-to-n-known)) but was not satisfactorily answered beyond my basic observations.

Let $\tau(k)$ be the number of divisors of the positive integer $k$.
How does $f(n)=\prod_{k\leq n} \tau(k)$ or a reasonable function of it, such as $\log f(n)$ grow with increasing $n$?

Gerry Myerson commented that it's tabulated at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A066843) but with no information on growth rate.

I noted that the upper bound (using the arithmetic geometric mean inequality and the sum of divisors of integers up to $n$) below holds
$$f(n)\leq (\log n)^n \left(1+\frac{2 \gamma -1}{n}\right).$$

This is a plot of $\log U$ and $\log f(n)$ where $U$ is the upperbound in (1).

[image]

This is a plot $U/f(n)$ where $U$ is the upperbound in (1).

[image]

Comment: Well, $f(n)=\log\tau(n)$ is an additive function; that is, $f(n) = \sum_{p^k\parallel n} f(p^k)$. Now insert this expression for $f$ into $\sum_{n \le x}f(n)$ and reverse the order of summation. I believe in this example, one finds that the main term in the asymptotic is $x \sum_{p \le x} f(p)/p$, and this is $\sim (\log 2) x\log\log{x}$, as $x\to \infty$ (Alternatively, note that $\tau(n)$ is between $2^{\omega(n)}$ and $2^{\Omega(n)}$, and use the known results --- as found in Hardy and Wright, for example --- on the partial sums of $\omega$ and $\Omega$.)

Comment: As above, $\log{\tau(n)} = \sum_{p^k || n}\log{(k+1)} = \sum_{p^k\vert n}\log{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}$. Thus $$\sum_{n\leq x} \log{\tau(n)} = \sum_{p^k\leq x} \log{\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^k}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: Since $\sum_{p\leq x}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\right\rfloor=\sum_{n\leq x}\omega(n)=x\log\log{x}+\sum_{i=0}^K \frac{a_i x}{(\log{x})^i}+O\left(\frac{x}{(\log{x})^{K+1}}\right)$ for some constants $a_i$, and $\sum_{p^k\leq x, k > 1}\frac{\log{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}{p^k}=\text{const.} + O(x^{-1/2})$, it follows that the asymptotic is $(\log{2})\log\log{x} + \widetilde{\text{const.}} x + (\log{2})\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{a_i x}{(\log{x})^i} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log{x})^{K+1}}\right)$. Hope I haven't made a mistake!

Comment: @alpoge: What you write is definitely fine for $K=0$. I am not so sure about $K>0$, because in the approximation $\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\rfloor=\frac{x}{p}+O(1)$, the $O(1)$ error term is not so easy to handle: it produces an error of $O(\pi(x))$ when treated crudely. That is, the asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{x}{p}$ does not readily yield the same kind of expansion for $\sum_{p\leq x}\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\rfloor$. (Perhaps a careful integration by parts, via $d\pi(t)$, yields the expansion for $K>0$, but I haven't verified this. At any rate, the case $K=0$ already solves the problem.)

Comment: Indeed! That's why I left it as floor(x/p) and used results on the average order of omega(n) instead (namely an expansion I found in work of Diaconis).

Comment: @alpoge: Very good. Actually I just realized I have answered the original question already, with the help of the same reference to Diaconis! See mathoverflow.net/questions/208827/product-of-tauk/208844

Comment: This question was asked already, so I will ask it to be closed: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208827/product-of-tauk

Comment: @GHfromMO: Oh brilliant! Funny how that happens! (Hopefully I've done this "@" construction correctly since nothing special shows up on my phone.)

Comment: @alpoge: I think it shows that it is easier to prove something than figuring out what to prove :-) It also shows that one's mental abilities (I mean my abilities) depend heavily on one's actual state of mind.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I now understand it's a duplicate, but the discussion here is still enlightening for me. Thanks to everyone who participated.

Comment: @kodlu and other readers: The credit goes to Ramanujan, of course. I enjoyed the discussion, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r_n(\lambda)=\#\{m:m\le n,\tau(m)\le 2^{e(n)}\}$ where $e(n)=\log\log n+\lambda (2\log\log n)^{1/2}.$ It is known (see [Note on the distribution of values of the arithmetic function $d\left( m \right)$](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1941-47-10/S0002-9904-1941-07575-0/home.html)) that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{r_n(\lambda)}{n}=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}e^{-u^2}du.$$
The main term $\log\log n$ in $e(n)$ gives asymptotic
$$\prod_{k\leq n} \tau(k)\approx 2^{n\log\log n}.$$

Probably next term in $e(n)$ assigned with rate of convergence (or some kind of [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) for $\tau(n)$) may give more precise result.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted my original answer, because I realized (thanks to user alpoge, see the comments below the original post) that I have already answered the same question earlier, with a much better analysis. Read my response [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208827/product-of-tauk/208844).